# nHibernate join query

Tags: nhibernate, join

i have two tables (graph representation - one table is nodes, other is link between nodes), and i want to write this query in nHibernate:

```
SELECT 
  distinct(t.id),  t.NodeName, e.Fk_linkOne, e.Fk_linkTwo, e.RelationName
FROM Nodes t
INNER JOIN NodeRelation e ON t.Id=e.Fk_linkOne OR t.Id=e.Fk_linkTwo
where (e.Fk_linkOne =84 OR e.Fk_linkTwo=84 ) AND t.Id!=84
```

I did not find how to connect two tables wiht join, that have OR in it..

```
ICriteria criteriaSelect = Session
  .CreateCriteria(typeof(NodeRelation ), "nodeRelations")                  
  .CreateCriteria("nodeRelations.Node", "node",
       NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
```

Comment: Do you have mappings you can show?

Answer (score 0):

You can only define your joins as per the associations you have defined in your mappings. As far as I know you can't define OR style relationships in Nhibernate. Consider using a self referential style graph representation.

```
public class Node
{
    public IList<Node> Parents { get; set; }
    public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
}

<bag name="Parents" table="Node_Relation">
   <key column="ChildId" />
   <many-to-many class="Node" column="ParentId" />
</bag>
<bag name="Children" table="Node_Relation">
   <key column="ParentId" />
   <many-to-many class="Node" column="ChildId" />
</bag>
```

Comment: This isn't entierly true. You can associate by any property, even using OR, but not with criteria. With HQL you could create   cartesian products and filter in the where clause. This is always an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using DetachedCriteria to get the same done. I am not sure about your query but I will jsut give a shot.

```
var dc1= DetachedCriteria.For(typeof( NodeRelation )).Add(Restrictions.Eq("Fk_linkOne", 84))
.SetProjection(Projections.Property("Fk_linkOne"));

var dc2= DetachedCriteria.For(typeof( NodeRelation )).Add(Restrictions.Eq("Fk_linkTwo", 84))
.SetProjection(Projections.Property("Fk_linkTwo"));

Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Nodes))
.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", dc1))
.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", dc2))
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", 84)).List<Nodes>;
```

Hope the above query is corrrect. please let me know if you cant get it to work after obs trying smethings and let me know wat u tried.

Comment: I thought about doing this too, but the problem is that this doesn't give him the fields he also needs from the NodeRelation table.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on your classes and not so much on your tables. Remember, you are using a ORM and you are working with a class model.

Assumed that your classes look like this:

```
class Node
{
  List<Node> Relations { get; private set; }
  List<Node> InverseRelations { get; private set; }
}
```

You may map it like this:

```
<class name="Node">
<!-- .... -->
  <bag name="Relations" table="NodeRelation">
    <key name="Fk_linkOne">
    <many-to-many class="Node" column="Fk_linkTwo"/>
  </bag>
  <bag name="InverseRelations" table="NodeRelation" inverse="true">
    <key name="Fk_linkTwo">
    <many-to-many class="Node" column="Fk_linkOne"/>
  </bag>

</class>
```

This way you get asymetrical relations (this means: when Node A relates to Node B, B isn't necessarily related to A, except of the InverseRelation of course). I don't know what you actually need, so this is an assumption based on your database design.

Your query may look like this:

```
from Node n
where 
  :x in elements(n.Relations)
  or :x in elements(n.InverseRelations)
```

Note: x is an entity type, not just an id (you need to load it using `session.Load<Node>(84)`),

Another way for the samy query:

```
select distinct n
from Node n 
  inner join n.Relations e1 
  inner join n.InverseRelations e2
where e1.id = 84 or e2.id = 84
```

Or another way without the use of the inverse relations:

```
select n
from Node n, Node n2 inner join n.Relations e
where
  (n = n2 and e.id = 84)
  OR (n = e and n2.id = 84)
```

In criteria I would take the second solution and write it like this:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Node>("n")
  .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct("n"))
  .CreateCriteria("Relations", "e1")
  .CreateCriteria("InverseRelations", "e2")
  .Add(Expression.Or(
    Expression.Eq("e1.id", 84),
    Expression.Eq("e2.id", 84));
```